# Finding a generating function for a formal power series containing $n$ and $a_n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, formal-power-series

Given the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$, the elements of which are recursively defined as follows:

$$a_0 := 0; a_{n+1} := n \cdot a_n + 1$$

We can define a formal power series 
$A(z) = \sum_{n\geq0}a_nz^n$ and after a few simplification steps we obtain:
$$A(z) = a_0 + z \cdot \sum_{n\geq0}n \cdot a_n \cdot z^n + z \cdot A(z)$$

My goal is to obtain a generating function by eliminating the power series but I am not sure how to proceed. None of the "simple" power series known to me fit the pattern of the power series above.

Is there some Identity I can use or is there another trick?

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Hint : What is
\begin{eqnarray*}
z \frac{d}{dz} A(z)=?
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: It should be, I think, $$A(z)=a_0+\sum_{n\geq 0} (na_n+1)z^{n+1}=a_0+z^2A'(z)+\frac{z}{1-z}$$

Comment: I was think how to get ride of $A'(z)?$ Can you give any clue$?$ @ThomasAndrews

Comment: I don't quite know how to solve this differential equation, sorry. @emonhossain

Comment: The terms of the sequence grow like a factorial, so there's no hope the ordinary generating function will be analytic.

Comment: Can you provide a complete solution? @RusMay . I'd also be interested, as I'm having trouble finding an closed form where $A'(z)$ pop up.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives
$$
A(z) = e^{-1/z} (c_1 + e E_i(1/z - 1)),
$$
where $$E_i(x) = -\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}t\ \mathsf dt $$ is the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ exponential integral.